# How can I set breakpoints at return of a function with regex

Tags: macos, debugging, breakpoints, lldb

I know I can use

```
br set -X foo -p return
```

to set breakpoints on a function foo's return. But I'd like to combine this with regex like so:

```
break set -r "\.MyClass\.foo.*" -p return
```

But in LLDB this gives me

```
$ error: invalid combination of options for the given command
```

Anyone knows if it is possible to combine regex and "-p return"?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what options one of the flavors of an lldb command takes (in this case `break set -p`) look at that entry in the initial lines of the help output.  For this command you see:

```
  breakpoint set [-ADHd] -p <regular-expression> [-G <boolean>] [-C <command>] [-c <expr>] [-i <count>] [-o <boolean>] [-q <queue-name>] [-t <thread-id>] [-x <thread-index>] [-T <thread-name>] [-N <breakpoint-name>] [-f <filename>] [-m <boolean>] [-s <shlib-name>] [-X <function-name>]
```

That doesn't take `-r` but it does take options to restrict the source search by function name, file name and shared library name.  These options can be repeated multiple times to build up an allow list, but they aren't regular expressions.

If you do need a regular expression matcher on the file or function, you could make your own without too much effort using:

https://lldb.llvm.org/use/python-reference.html#using-the-python-api-s-to-create-custom-breakpoints

Your breakpoint resolver would apply your search logic to the SBSymbolContext your matcher gets asked to look into, and if you find file or function matches of interest.  Then either do the text search by hand or call `SBTarget.BreakpointCreateBySourceRegularExpression` with the appropriate files & function list which will search the text for your source pattern and copy those found locations to your breakpoint.